# PHP file_get_contents changing apersand in URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
$Link = 'http://somewebsite.com/api.php?message=someMessage&user_id=' . $UserID . '&password=' . $UserPW;
echo $Link;
echo "<br><br>";

$PageResponse = file_get_contents($Link);
```

for privacy i cannot post a working example, however this is the problem I am experiencing.

when i echo the $Link it returns this:

```
 http://somewebsite.com/api.php?message=someMessage&user_id=redacted&password=redacted
```

however the file_get_contents returns and error that looks like this:

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(http://somewebsite.com/api.php?message=someMessage&amp;user_id=redacted&amp;password=redacted): failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\wamp64\www\hello.php on line 14
```

if you will notice, it is changing the "&" character to `&amp;` which breaks the url. Is there an easy way to address this?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature

Comment: Have you tried to `html_entity_decode` the url string before using `file_get_contents`? Otherwise an `str_replace` would help.

Comment: have tried decode and replace. conversion still persists

Answer (score 0):

You can make a array of your data. Than serialize it to make it as string.
Now we should use openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt.

You can do something like:

```
    $password          = "EaaJgaD0uFDEg7tpvMOqKfAQ46Bqi8Va";
$data              = [
    'message'  => 'someMessage',
    'user_id'  => '111',
    'password' => 'paaa'
];
$string_to_encrypt = serialize( $data );

$encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt( $string_to_encrypt, "AES-128-ECB", $password );
//print_r($encrypted_string);
$_SESSION["encrypted_value"] = $encrypted_string;
```

Now your encrypted data have on session so you can get it anywhere from your site.
Now get your data like that

```
 $encrypted_value = $_SESSION["encrypted_value"];
$decrypted_string=openssl_decrypt($encrypted_value,"AES-128-ECB",$password);
//print_r($decrypted_string);
$result = unserialize($decrypted_string);
print_r($result);
```

Finally you will get an array.

You must need to start your session

> session_start();